# free function and inheritance

Tags: c++

I am trying a basic thing with two classes and a free functions. First I have two classes :

```
struct BASE{
    BASE(int a = 0):a_(a){};
    virtual ~BASE(){};
    virtual void foo(){std::cout << "BASE " << std::endl;}
    int a_;
};

struct DERIVED: public BASE{
    DERIVED():BASE(){};
    void foo(){std::cout << "DERIVED " << std::endl;}
};
```

then I fill up a std::vector (or boost::ptr_vector)

```
std::vector<BASE* > vec;    
vec.push_back( new BASE(2));
vec.push_back( new DERIVED);
```

If I call my function foo, no pb the virtual stuff works well,
but  if I create two free functions :

```
void foo(BASE*   a, DERIVED*   b){
    std::cout << " mix base/derived " << std::endl;
}

void foo(BASE*   a, BASE*   b){
    std::cout << " full base " << std::endl;
}
```

if I do

```
foo(vec[0], vec[1]); //failed
```

I will get the message

```
full base
```

Well it is logical because I have vector of BASE*, but does it exist anyway 
to get the good call to my free function ? I need the inheritance so I can not really separate the 2 classes because I must fill up this container

Moreover at the end my vector will be fill up randomly, so I can not know by advance how cast properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest (and quickest) way to get workaround is to introduce one more virtual function to unique identify derived classes (using `int`, `enum` values or `typeid`). So later you may call it and realize what exact derived class (or maybe base) you've got behind the `BASE*`, and do `dynamic_cast` to that type.

You gave no details about what problem you are trying to solve... just make sure that you've done a complete reaseach for existed solutions if you want to implement a [Double Dispatch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_dispatch) (or some kind of)...

But usually, if you need `dynamic_cast` it means that smth wrong with you design (OOP model of domain)...

Comment: if you use a hand made RTTI (enum etc) you don't need `dynamic_cast`, `static_cast` is enough

Comment: not quite correct! consider multiple inheritance (a romb-like)

Comment: Well I am making linear algebra between matrices. Presently I have a dense matrix class. When you multiply matrices C = A*B, you call the blas GEMM solver. But if one of your matrices is an identity matrix, you should just return A or B and call nothing. Presently, the ID matrices is based on a matrices class, it is not optimal, I allocate useless memory, and call DGEMM for nothing. My matrices fill up a vector and operations are performed randomly. I try to simplify a maximum in this example. Agree I should avoid the dynamic_cast

Comment: @Timocafé: it would have helped if you had included that bit of information. What about a `virtual bool IsIdentityMatrix() const` method?

Comment: Well I implemented a solution with an enum, but your proposition is also very nice (and better), thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Just as you don't know in advance what your `vec[i]` is, so doesn't the compiler. Function overload resolution is a compile time process, while polymorphism - run time.

Thus it calls the `void foo(BASE*   a, BASE*   b)` version.

In other words, what you want to do is impossible, unless you use `dynamic_cast` to try to cast to every possible derived class. It will return `0` if the object is of wrong type.

However, many people will argue that use of  `dynamic_cast` is indication of bad design. And it's expensive as well.

Answer (score 0):

You need dynamic dispatching for that, something like this:

```
void foo(BASE *a, BASE *b) {
  if (DERIVED *bb = dynamic_cast<DERIVED*>(b)) {
    foo(a, bb);
  } else {
    std::cout << " full base " << std::endl;
  }
}
```

If you don't want to use a `dynamic_cast`, you could add a virtual function to `BASE` which would return some form of class identifier (e.g. an `enum`), override this in each derived class and then fork the call based on the return value of this function (along with `static_cast`).

Comment: I should avoid dynamic cast, I will try an enum